# Using external action output in outer git action step

Tags: github, devops, github-actions

I have this git action for my build

```
...
         - name: Building S3 Instance
             uses: charlie87041/s3-actions@main
             id: s3
             env:
               AWS_S3_BUCKET: 'xxx'
               AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: 'xxx'
               AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: 'xxxxx'
               AWS_REGION: 'xxx'
          - name: Updating EC2 [Develop] instance
            uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
            with:
              host: ${{secrets.EC2HOST}}
              key: ${{secrets.EC2KEY}}
              username: xxx
              envs: TESTING
              script: |
                cd ~/devdir
                export BUCKET_USER=${{steps.s3.outputs.user_id}}
                export BUCKET_USER_KEY=${{steps.s3.outputs.user_key}}
                docker login
                docker-compose down --remove-orphans
                docker system prune -a -f
                docker pull yyyy
                docker-compose up -d
```

And this is the important function in `charlie87041/s3-actions@main`

```
generate_keys () {
    RSP=$(aws iam create-access-key --user-name $USER);
    BUCKET_ACCESS_ID=$(echo $RSP | jq -r '.AccessKey.AccessKeyId');
    BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo $RSP | jq -r '.AccessKey.SecretAccessKey');
    echo "user_id=$BUCKET_ACCESS_ID" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "user_key=$BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    echo "::set-output name=BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY::$BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY"
    echo "::set-output name=BUCKET_ACCESS_ID::$BUCKET_ACCESS_ID"
}
```

I need to update env variables in container with  `BUCKET_USER` and `BUCKET_USER_KEY`, but these always return null when echo the container. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not that `set-output` was [deprecated recently (oct. 2022)](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/)

> If you are using self-hosted runners make sure they are updated to version 2.297.0 or greater.

If you are using runner on github.com directly, you would need to change

```
echo "::set-output name=BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY::$BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY"
```

with

```
echo "BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY=$BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

I am not sure an export within the script would work.
Using with directives, as [in issue 154](https://github.com/appleboy/ssh-action/issues/154#issuecomment-1066896140) might be more effective

```yaml
with:
  BUCKET_USER: ${{steps.s3.outputs.user_id}}
  ...
script: |
  ...
```